# How do I clear a (RecyclerView) SortedList?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, sortedlist

I have a SortedList I'm using to represent my data for a recycler view, but I'm struggling to "clear" the data between API calls. Any help? I'm currently just looping through the list like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < mList.size(); i++){
   removeItemAt(i);
}
```

This appears to inconsistently remove some items?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: added a clear method for next release.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the [source code](https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support@f0f363707e53c83688ee66a029885685de398dd0/.tree/v7/recyclerview/src/android/support/v7/util/SortedList.java#startline=230&endline=230), the problem with what you're doing is that `SortedList` changes the size when `removeItemAt` index is called. So `mList.size()` will change while your `for` loop is iterating causing inconsistent results.

Here is a way to remove items from a recyclerview `SortedList`.

```
public void clear() {
     mList.beginBatchedUpdates();
     //remove items at index 0 so the remove callback will be batched
     while (mList.size() > 0) {
         mList.remove(mList.get(0));
     }
     mList.endBatchedUpdates();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The new version of the support library has a `SortedList#clear()` method that you can use.